# Read value of local txt-File automaticly

Tags: javascript, html, file-io

What I want to reach:
[image]

I want to create a HTML Document, wich is able to precompile any Code or text.
More specific: If the precompiler find this "#include C://additionalCode.txt"
it replace that String(#include C://additionalCode.txt") with the value of the given path(C://additionalCode.txt).

I'm able to replace chars or words in a String. But I don't know how I can read a local File and get the value of this file in a String. Is JavaScript able to read local files automaticly?

Perfect would be a Function like this:

ExmapleText: "The Code you need is this #include C://code.txt"

```
function getFileValue(path){
...
return fileval; // fileval is the Value of the File in a String
```

After the file is readed i show the new Text or Code in the second Textarea.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript, in a web page, is absolutely forbidden from making the browser go and read arbitrary files from the user's hard disk. It would be a huge security risk.

The [File API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) allows access to files that the user picks.

Comment: hi Quentin, Would JavaScript be able to read a File if it would not be a web page?

Comment: That depends more on what it is than what it is not. A command line app written using Node.js, for example? Sure.

Comment: Have you an example wich I can use?

Comment: `node -e "console.log(require('fs').readFileSync('$HOME/tmp/123.txt', { encoding: 'utf-8' }));"`

Comment: It's very unpleasent for me to ask this, but I m a total newbie in JS. Could you show me how it can be realised to include the value from an File B into a File A wich should precompiled?

Comment: I don't even understand the question.

Comment: :D Sorry. I'm asking myself how could my Question with the HTML Document realised with node. It's the first time I'm reading about node.js.